# Role based auth with azure ad and db

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have asp.net core mvc app that has only login with azure ad. What I want to do is. User logs in with their microsoft account and then it looks to my db, gets rights and then sets roles to user. So basically: clicks login --> sings in with his acc --> I look to db and set his roles --> He can now acces only some content. I really dont know how to do it so thanks for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different answer. Try out the [Add authorization using app roles & roles claims to an ASP.NET Core web app thats signs-in users with the Microsoft identity platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/README.md) sample to see how the new [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) is used to work with Azure AD's app roles.

You'd replace the Azure AD's roles with yours and it should satisfy your requirement.